# Kotlin provide type when generate instance from generic class

Tags: generics, kotlin

Somehow I able to make many generic class by example below

```
val company = Fragment<Company>
val location= Fragment<Location>
val employee = Fragment<Employee>
```

In order to make the code simple, I decide to put all the class into list and generate class for each of them in a for loop

```
data class FragmentType(val entityClass: KClass<*>)
private val fragmentList: List<FragmentType> = listOf(
    FragmentType(Company::class),
    FragmentType(Location::class),
    FragmentType(Employee::class)
)

for(f in fragmentList){
    val fragment = Fragment<f.entityClass> //This is wrong
}
```

I know the line in the for loop is wrong, how can I use a variable to decide the type of generic that I am going to generate?

Comment: Some more context for what you're trying to achieve would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `enum` in that case:

```
enum class FragmentType {
    COMPANY, LOCATION, EMPLOYEE
}

for(f in FragmentType.values()) {
    val fragment = when (f) {
        FragmentType.COMPANY -> Fragment<Company>
        FragmentType.LOCATION -> Fragment<Location>
        FragmentType.EMPLOYEE -> Fragment<Employee>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enum (the answer above) isn't necessary.

```
val fragment = when(f.entityClass) {
    is Company -> Fragment<Company>
    is Location -> Fragment<Location>
    is Employee -> Fragment<Employee>
    else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("doesn't support class ${f.entityClass}")
}
```